# Amazon S3 file requests

Tags: php, amazon-s3, download

I'm trying to figure out how I could do both, force downloads of MP3 files from my Amazon S3 bucket and also allow them to be opened by the browser.

How can I control a link to either force a download or play the MP3 in the browser?

Doing some research, I've seen examples to do one or the other, but I need to be able to do both for each file depending on which link is clicked.

I'm using PHP to script my site.

Comment: if you can do one or other, what's the problem here?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to passing the file through my server or having 2 copies of the file on Amazon S3 with different headers.